# Respond with large amount of objects through a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, csv, export

I currently have an API for one of my projects and a service that is responsible for generating export files as CSVs, archive and store them somewhere in the cloud.

Since my API is written in Rails and my service in plain Ruby, I use the Her gem in the service to interact with the API. But I find my current implementation less performant, since I do a `Model.all` in my service, which in turn triggers a request that may contain way too many objects in the response.

I am curious on how to improve this whole task. Here's what I've thought of:

- implement pagination at API level and call `Model.where(page: xxx)` from my service;
- generate the actual CSV at API level and send the CSV back to the service (this may be done sync or async).

If I were to use the first approach, how many objects should I retrieve per page? How big should a response be?

If I were to use the second approach, this would bring quite an overhead to the request (and I guess API requests shouldn't take that long) and I also wonder whether it's really the API's job to do this.

What approach should I follow? Or, is there something better that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a lot of information through a ruby process, that's always not simple, I don't think you're missing anything here.

If you decide to generate CSVs at the API level then what do you get with maintaining the service? You could just ditch the service altogether because replacing your service with an nginx proxy would do the same thing better (if you're just streaming the response from API host)?

If you decide to paginate, there will be a performance reduction for sure, but nobody can tell you exactly how much you should paginate - bigger pages will be faster and consume more memory (reducing throughput by being able to run less workers), smaller pages will be slower and consume less memory but demand more workers because of IO wait times,

exact numbers will depend on the IO response times of your API app and the cloud and your infrastructure, I'm afraid no one can give you a simple answer you can follow without experimentation with a stress test, and once you set up a stress test, you will get a number of your own anyway - better than anybody's estimate.

A suggestion, write a bit more about your problem, constraints you are working under etc and maybe someone can help you with a bit more radical solution. For some reason I get the feeling that what you're really looking for is a background processor like sidekiq or delayed job, or maybe connect your service to the DB directly through a DB view if you are anxoius to decouple your apps, or an nginx proxy for API responses, or nothing at all... but I really can't tell without more information.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion! I don't want to connect directly to the DB from the service for the sake of isolation; I would then need models in multiple places, and since the service is not Rails, I would have a hard time doing this (been through this already). I can't also ditch the service; this CSV feature is just a part of what the service does. Regarding background processing, you refer to my second point, doing it the async way?

Comment: About constraints, I'm just looking to decouple components; the CSV generation will happen only once per day, and since it's inside a separate service, I guess it won't affect anything if it'll take a bit more to run.

Comment: How about generating the CSV in the API app in a cron job or background processor and simply serving it by the Service when requested?

Comment: Another option would be to create a DB view, maintain it from the API project and access it from the service - think of the view as being equivalent to API's controller action servicing the Service - if the DB changes you change the view too to return what the CSV feature needs, you can simply select from it via raw ruby or include "just" `ActiveRecord` in the project, something generally in these lines - https://rietta.com/blog/2013/11/28/rails-and-sql-views-for-a-report/

Comment: If I generate the CSV in the API and serve it to the service is basically my second bullet, with the async option, right? DB views sound interesting, but I guess there's too much work "off" the conventions, leading in much more work and maintenance to be done. I'd rather leave this option aside unless there is a really strong argument in its favour. All in all, you've also listed some possibilities, but if you were to choose one, which one would it be?

Comment: From what I see I would probably stream the csv response from API and then stream again the same string from the service

Comment: Not sure I've understood correctly: stream where from the API? In the API I have a DB connection so I can retrieve the data directly from the DB.

Comment: Yes, I would stream the request on the API side, and then stream it again from the service to the client if necessary (API -> service -> client)

Comment: Thanks for your answers and detailed explications. Will mark this as accepted and also award the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

I think it really depends how you want do define 'performance' and what your goal for your API is. Do you want to make sure no request to your API takes longer than 20msec to respond, than adding pagination would be a reasonable approach. Especially if the CSV generation is just an edge case, and the API is really built for other services. The number of items per page would then be limited by the speed at which you can deliver them. Your service would not be particularly more performant (even less so), since it needs to call the service multiple times.

Creating an async call (maybe with a webhook as callback) would be worth adding to your API if you think it is a valid use case for services to dump the whole record set.

Having said that, I think strictly speaking it is the job of the API to be quick and responsive. So maybe try to figure out how caching can improve response times, so paging through all the records is reasonable. On the other hand it is the job of the service to be mindful of the amount of calls to the API, so maybe store old records locally and only poll for updates instead of dumping the whole set of records each time.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Indeed, the CSV generation is an edge case, normally the service won't need that much data to get from the API. Regarding the limit, since I send serialized objects back from the API, they will have some bytes in size, and I was wondering how big (in size) a response may be. Regarding async and webhooks, since it's a rare operation, I guess I'll let my service app "wait" until the API sends everything; or is async really worth it in this case? As a conclusion, do you have any other approach in mind? Because I feel you're saying either option isn't good enough.

Comment: Well, I were in that situation I would most likely also go for the pragmatic approach and create the CSV on api-side maybe with another respond_to block. Size shouldn't be an issue unless we talk about several (dozen) megabytes. Then memory consumption might be a problem. Ruby Socket connections have default response-timeouts, I believe that might hit even before a size limit.

Comment: Streaming the response might be a nice way of lowering the impact on memory and database. [This](http://smsohan.com/blog/2013/05/09/genereating-and-streaming-potentially-large-csv-files-using-ruby-on-rails/) might help.

Comment: Pagination takes a lot of IO time, also complicates exception handling, nudgind the responses into <20ms times is sometimes hard and sometimes impossible due to infrastructure, that's why I didn't consider it as a viable solution, I base it from a failed experience with loading huge pages with 1000s of records by using `find_each`, on small datasets it was unnecessary and on large datasets it was simply not viable, whatever a Rails driven solution can give it'll be at least an order of magnitude slower then a round-trip to postgres